# Analog movement when emulating keyboard/mouse with Steam controller

Tags: hardware, controllers

I have a Steam Controller on the way and I'm interested in using it for games e.g. Fallout 4.

I'd prefer it if the controller would emulate the keyboard, rather than the gamepad, so that I have more options for button mappings, etc.
That said, it would be nice if I could have analog movement as opposed to the digital movement provided by WASD/ESDF.

Does this functionality exist with the Steam controller, or does the controller work in a way that otherwise assuages my concern?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, as most games don't support using the controller and keyboard at the same time anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you will be at the mercy of the developer.

As Hugo has mentioned, **some** games implement their controller support to work exclusive to keyboard control.  You can't do much about that if you want to retain analog use.

For games that do it properly, you will be able to map your controller with more options.

You may be able to supplement shortcomings by using something like AutoHotKey, but that takes a level of know-how.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that may be useful is that the Steam Controller can emulate a gamepad and a keyboard and a mouse at the same time. Some games don't support this, but for those that do you could easily configure the controller in a hybrid way.